# Stripe: card holder name verification

Tags: java, stripe-payments, payment-processing

How can I implement this scenario:

1) When making payment with credit card user puts in the form his/her first name and last name

2) If first and last name entered to not match first and last name ("printed") on the card - we (myself or stripe) reject transaction.

As I see in examples (https://stripe.com/docs/custom-form#step-1-collecting-credit-card-information), to create new token Stripe.js uses only: Card Number, Expiration (MM/YY), CVC.

My back-end is on Java. 
As I see, neither ['Charge'](https://stripe.com/docs/api/java#charge_object) object, nor ['Customer'](https://stripe.com/docs/api/java#customer_object) do not have properties such as 'first name', 'last name'

On Quora I found an answer from a Stripe employee, stating that it is possible:

> "You can also send us more data, such as billing address and
>   cardholder name. Stripe can compare the billing address entered by the
>   customer against that on file with their bank. This is also a useful
>   indicator for determining whether the payment is being made by the
>   genuine cardholder."
>
> https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-bare-minimum-information-that-Stripe-requires-to-charge-a-credit-card

But how do I implement this?

Comment: Java != JavaScript. And [Identity Verification for Managed Accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification).

Comment: The page at the link you posted says: *Although optional, using address and postal code verifications is highly recommended as they'll help reduce fraud. The complete list of fields you can provide is available in the Stripe.js reference*. If you click on the Stripe.js reference link, you can read all the fields you can send, and a link to a page explaining how to write rules based on the address.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Java is commonly used for web back-ends, so I see no reason to assume he didn't mean Java. Also, your link has nothing at all to do with verifying cardholder information.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately, most banks don't provide any way to verify the cardholder's name. This tends to surprise people, since most merchants do request the cardholder's name.

The main standard for sending messages over the credit card networks, [ISO8583](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8583), doesn't even contain a field to transmit the cardholder name.

Most merchants tend to use the CVC and address for verification, since address verification (AVS) is usable in many countries.

See also: https://www.quora.com/How-is-a-cardholder-name-used-when-you-pay-with-a-credit-card-online

Comment: can you provide a more official article about the topic? i can't find any other than the one in Quora. still search...