# Stripe Checkout requires user name. Elements doesn't. Should I collect user's name?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe to set up recurring payments on my app.

Using Stripe [elements](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/set-up-subscription) to do this, the form that Stripe loads into the app **does not** collect user name.

That is fine by me, because I prefer not to have access to the user's name.

But, Stripe [checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/subscriptions/starting), the form that loads if you redirect to Stripe's own checkout form, **does** require user name.

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59648750/stripe-checkout-without-requiring-name-or-email) to see if I could remove user name from the Stripe checkout form, but it looks like the answer is no.

So, one main Stripe method for taking payments (checkout) requires user name, while the other (elements) does not.

Do I need to collect the user's name on my payment form? Put another way, is it ok for me to use elements and, consistent with the Stripe default, **not** collect user name?

Comment: You can either collect the user's name on your own (in the form but outside of Elements), or not collect it. The main reason you'd collect it is that it's more information to help avoid declines.

Comment: Thank you. Why does it help avoid declines? As I said, I prefer to avoid collecting that kind of personal info, but I also want to be sure my payments collection is secure. (I also think it is strange that checkout and elements have opposite approaches on this issue.)

Comment: I wouldn't say that Elements has an opinion or approach, collecting the name is just out of scope(Elements is a PCI-compliance-friendly way of accepting only the sensitive card details themselves, you'd white-label and use it as part of a larger form that collects other info). Collecting the cardholder name is generally [recommended](https://stripe.com/docs/disputes/prevention#collect-information) as an online merchant(for example, if you are seeing 100 payment attempts with different numbers but the same name, that's a good sign of fraud), but it's not absolutely required.

Comment: Thanks. Right now, if I collect the name as part of payment, it's saved on the Stripe dashboard, where I can view it. Is there any way for me to make it so I can't see the name? I am ok with Stripe seeing it. I would just prefer that I am not able to.